# Output the time correctly

Tags: ruby, time

When you use the `Time` class in Ruby, if the time is below 10 it will drop the zero and only output the corresponding integer, for example:

```
def time_test
  t = Time.now
  puts "#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec}"
end

5.times do
  time_test
  sleep(20)
end

#<= 11:48:24
#<= 11:48:44
#<= 11:49:4
#<= 11:49:24
#<= 11:49:44
#=> 5
```

Now my question is this. Say I wanted to add the zero where it belongs and wanted the time to look, like it does on a microwave (minus the 12 hour clock part). With `hour:min:sec`

How would I got about making the script output the zero if the sec, min, or hour is below 10? Example of expected output:

```
#<= 11:48:24
#<= 11:48:44
#<= 11:49:04 #<=
#<= 11:49:24
#<= 11:49:44
#=> 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

```
Time.now.strftime("%T")
# => "03:00:42"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strftime` method.

```
 Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Or more concise

```
Time.now.strftime("%T")
```

I used [this documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)